# Rails 3.1rc4 defaults.js not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a brand new Rails 3.1rc4 project. After generating a scaffold, migrating and creating a new entry I noticed that I could not destroy the entry I had just created.

It turns out that "/assets/defaults.js" can't be found so the destroy confirmation dialog isn't popped up.

I figure this might have something to do with the new asset pipeline, but searching for solutions has not helped me out much.

Any idea why defaults.js can't be found?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sigh, I've found the answer but since I have less than 100 reputation I am unable to answer my own question for 8 hours. Thanks SO!

Comment: @Marek  I've added the answer I had originally typed up. Sorry for not getting back to you sooner.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Don't feel bad, i also find out on my own and forgot to post the answer :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's most likely because the reference to

```
javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

is still in the application layout. That reference should be changed to

```
javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the issue - somehow (through a gem, probably) my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file was changed from

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

to

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

Changing it back to the original fixed my issue.