# Delete Method Doesn't Work in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

My current code looks like this:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "hchq.js", "bootstrap-image-gallery.js", "bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js", "load-image.min.js", "media.js", "jquery", "bootstrap.js", "jquery.dataTables.js", "DT_bootstrap.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

However, I keep getting:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/defaults.js"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Digging into the problem more I found: [Rails 3.1rc4 defaults.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359860/rails-3-1rc4-defaults-js-not-found) that suggested I take defaults line  out. I take it out and the 404 goes away, but with it in and with it out I can't issue a delete request. It just directs me to the show page.

Any idea on what's going on and how can I solve this so I don't get the 404 and can issue a delete request?

Update:

Here is the actual delete link: `<%= link_to 'Delete', client_path(client), method: "delete", class: "label label-important" %>` which produces the following html: `<a href="/clients/2" class="label label-important" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>` which seems right to me.

and here is the line from the log:

```
Started GET "/clients/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 16:50:23 -0500
Processing by ClientsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Client Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  Rendered clients/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 45.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/assets/defaults.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-27 16:50:23 -0500
Served asset /defaults.js - 404 Not Found (4ms)
```

Another thing I tried is getting rid of the defaults line, as that is pre-rails 3.1, and using "application" as the only thing inside the javascript_include_tag and I still have this issue.

Comment: What happens if you move `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` above the other `javascript_include_tag`?

Comment: @ScottJShea That didn't make any difference.

Comment: Try using a symbol, instead of a string.

Comment: @MurifoX That doesn't work. It still just redirects to the show page.

Comment: Do you have a `resources :clients` in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: @MurifoX, I do. I moved it to the top, since it was second to last and it didn't fix it as should be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only plausible explanation has to do with the CRSF token Rails forms expect when having a non-GET action coming to hit the server. When you build a form in rails, you have a token that is passed to the server for purpose of security. This is automatically built-in when you use the `form_for` and `form_tag` helpers (forms uses POSTS and stuff).

Because of the `protect_from_forgery` in your `application_controller`, rails don't let you do POST/DELETE/PUT from outside a form, that's why the `link_to` doesn't work, it is just a link, trying to do a POST. But if you comment this line, the link would work just fine.

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 2):

Changing Link_to to Button_to fixed it.

Why?

Comment: I believe `button_to` wraps the link inside a form. I will post a most detailed answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your delete link is just a link, js magic converts it to a form which is then posted. That's why the form worked, and the link didn't - it must be just staying a link.

As to why the delete link didn't work, you are missing the js file (hence 404), or have an error in the js if you get the js include right, the link will be transformed by the helper. Check your js console in the browser and look for errors.

Your link is sending you to a get request, so obviously the built-in rails js is failing to convert the link.